# Youtube player is not being displayed in mobile browsers

Tags: video, youtube, embedding

My website displays embedded Youtube video player in desktop browsers but nothing in mobile. Nothing shows up instead a blank space created for youtube player. Here is a sample link:

http://nepali.rocks/1974-ad-hinda-hindai-4/187467

Comment: You should add more information about your problem - browser, code, ...

Comment: I don't know about the code. however, I assume CSS is blocking the player. I saw similar reply to another question.

While talking about browser, all browsers are showing just spaces.

Comment: I think the downvotes are unfair but @Andrew makes a good point. In fact the solution lies in the HTML source code of your page. If I had not chosen to check it myself then I couldnt have answered you. Help us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason Youtube Player is not displaying on mobile is because your link seems to embed a version of the Youtube Player that runs via the Flash Player browser plugin (which is not available in most mobile browser apps. I think Dolphin and Firefox apps can show Flash Player content if you need it on mobile).

[image]

**To Fix:** 
replace `http://www.youtube.com/v/` with `http://youtube.com/embed/`

Simply change the Youtube embed code like shown below...

- Find: `src="http://www.youtube.com/v/ufpFzbcshNc?rel=1"`
- Replace:   `src="http://youtube.com/embed/ufpFzbcshNc?rel=1"`

Now this method gives the HTML5 version of the Youtube Player. Hopefully working on any mobile browser. Hope it helps.

[image]